# separating image after watershed using emgu.cv

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, watershed

i have a blood image and i applied watershed on it .. its works and determines the cells but i don't know how to put each cell in a separate image .. i'm working with emgu.cv can i get some help

here i segment the picture using my watershed method and then put the marker on the original image

```
Image<Gray, Int32> boundaryImage = watershedSegmenter.Process(image);
Image<Gray, Byte> test = watershedSegmenter.GetWatersheds(); Image<Bgr, byte>dest=new Image<Bgr, byte>(image.Width, image.Height);
dest = image.And(image, test);            
pictureBox1.Width = boundaryImage.ToBitmap().Width;
pictureBox1.Height = boundaryImage.ToBitmap().Height;
pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = boundaryImage.ToBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like EMGUcv cvWatershed() is having some bugs which is not yet resolved. The Marker Image is always returning white image. Can you share your 1st stage output images?
 I'm not able to view any images by using this code.

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> image = Img_Source_Bgr.Copy();
Image<Gray, Int32> marker = new Image<Gray, Int32>(image.Width, image.Height);
Rectangle rect = image.ROI;
marker.Draw(
new CircleF(
new PointF(rect.Left + rect.Width / 2.0f, rect.Top + rect.Height / 2.0f),
    /*(float)(Math.Min(image.Width, image.Height) / 20.0f)*/ 5.0f),
new Gray(255),
0);
Image<Bgr, Byte> result = image.ConcateHorizontal(marker.Convert<Bgr, byte>());
Image<Gray, Byte> mask = new Image<Gray, byte>(image.Size);
CvInvoke.cvWatershed(image, marker);
CvInvoke.cvCmpS(marker, 0.10, mask, CMP_TYPE.CV_CMP_GT);

imageBox1.Image = mask;
```

Comment: i use the code that's written in this page and it is work  >> http://yy-programer.blogspot.com/2012/11/emgucv-image-process-transforming_29.html >> sorry for being late